# Packaging NPAPI plugin for Mac App Store

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, safari-extension

I have a Safari extension built using NPAPI plugin. It was built by a contractor but I was asked to package it up for the Mac App Store. 
Now I don't even know if this is possible as it was not built using Cocoa and when I use xcode to Archive it, I get a Generic Xcode Archive as the Archive Type instead of a Mac App Archive, that wont validate.
1. Can this be done in the first place?
2. If so, how do I go about creating the right Archive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't distribute an NPAPI plugin via the App Store:

> **2.15**: Apps must be self-contained, single application installation bundles, and cannot install code or resources in shared locations

An NPAPI plugin isn't an application, and in order to work must be installed in a shared location (the system or user plugin directory), so doesn't meet the App Store criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to create a blank Mac Application as a wrapper for my NPAPI code so that it can be installed as a Single Application Bundle?

Comment: That's clearly addressed in my answer: "Apps [...] cannot install code or resources in shared locations". "An NPAPI plugin [...] must be installed in a shared location". What good would an NPAPI plugin sitting in an app bundle, not detected or loaded by any browser, do?

Comment: My sentiments exactly. Thanks!